# MongoDB: current sum of fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

we has documents

```
{a: 1}
{a: 5}
{a: 3}
```

How to aggrerage data with calc current sum?

```
{a: 1, cs: 1}
{a: 5, cs: 6}
{a: 3, cs: 9}
```

Comment: `db.c.aggregate({_id:'$a', cs: {$sum: 1}})` By the looks of your question unless the count comes from else where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this sort of thing at current in MongoDB with mapReduce. The reason is that is is presently the **only** place that can hold a *"global"* variable, and that is basically what you need for a *"running total"*:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function(){ 
        totals += this.a;
        emit(this._id, {"a": this.a, "cs": totals});
    },
    function() {},  // nothing to reduce here
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 },
        "scope": { "totals": 0 }
    }
);
```

So there is "no actual grouping here", but you could do so if you wanted to. The point is that this maintains a "running total" per record, which is what you seem to be asking.

The ["mapReduce"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) command has an aspect called "scope" used here to implement a "global" variable that can be used for such a task.